# Maximal connected subtopologies

Tags: gn.general-topology

This is related to [an older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201477/maximal-connected-topologies).

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Trivially, the indiscrete topology $\{\emptyset, X\}$ is a connected subtopology of $\tau$.

Is there a connected topology $\tau_c\subseteq \tau$ on $X$ such that whenever $\tau_c'$ is a connected topology on $X$ such that $\tau_c\subseteq\tau_c'\subseteq \tau$ then $\tau_c=\tau_c'$?

Comment: The answer I gave below is incorrect; as pointed out by a comment to it, the union of a chain of topologies is not necessarily a topology. I think you should un-accept it.

Comment: Thanks for putting the effort into it... I also missed the fact that the union of a chain of topologies need not be a topology! Can you delete your answer and post as a comment, why a straightforward application of Zorn's lemma doesn't work?

Comment: The straightforward application of Zorn's lemma doesn't work because one of the conditions on topologies uses infinitely many sets (in fact, arbitrarily many). An example: let $X = \mathbb{N}, \tau_n$ be the topology that doesn't distinguish between $m \geq n$, and otherwise is discrete. Then $\cup \tau_n$ is the set of "eventually constant" sets (and even is countable). But it does include each of the point-sets, which contradicts the "arbitrary unions" condition on topologies. Therefore, Zorn's lemma can't be directly applied.

Comment: Yes.  Let $\tau_c=\tau$. ;-)

Comment: @ForeverMozart -- works fine if $\tau$ is connected, but if it isn't?

Comment: Just in a way of additional relevant information - the (accepted) answer to the linked question refers to [a paper](https://msp.org/pjm/1974/51-1/p02.xhtml) with an example of a connected Hausdorff topology having no maximal connected topologies above it.

Comment: Split the real line into countably many disjoint dense sets $A_n$, e.g., $A_n=\mathbb{Q}+n\pi$ for $n\ge1$ and $A_0=\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{n\ge1}A_n$. Let $\tau_n$ be the topology generated by the usual topology together with $\{A_i:i\le n\}$. Each topology is connected, yet the union generates a topology with a pairwise disjoint cover by open sets.